# How to fill the first page in a site that we see when we enter the site with image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting

I'm coding a website with wordpress. I want to fill the home page(site link : tibitipi.cf) with this minecraft image. As you can see there is a little space under the image. I watched a lot of video about it but i can't learn that how can i cover the entry page. For example in https://uczpre.com/ site there is a pink image that cover the entry page. How can i cover the entry page in wordpress ? Thanks for your suggestion.   [The problem photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcDOZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a background image for the body element and make it cover the hole page:

`body { background-image: url(yourimagepath.jpg); background-size: cover; }`

Maybe you want to do it inside a container, you can make sure it fits the height of the screen:

`.bg_container { height:100vh; background-image: url(yourimagepath.jpg); background-size: cover;  }`

You can also position it, because the `cover` will always take up all space. On mobile for example, you want to center und it horizontally:

`.bg_container { background-position: center center; }`

So `cover` will make your background image take the full height of your element, and with `background-position` you can align it horizontal.

Hope this helps!